# What is the meaning about the $\alpha$ in TD3 algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, mathematics, actor-critic

I am study the paper with TD3 algorithm.

I am curious about the meaning of $\alpha$ while the paper prove that overestimation will be happened in a critical situation.

The contents about mathematical proof is like ...

$\exists \epsilon_1 \ s.t \ \alpha \leq \epsilon_1 \implies \ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q_\theta(s,\pi_{approx}(s))]\geq\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q_\theta(s,\pi_{true}(s))]$

$\exists \epsilon_2 \ s.t \ \alpha \leq \epsilon_2 \implies \mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q^\pi(s,\pi_{true}(s))]\geq\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q^\pi(s,\pi_{approx}(s))]$

And the overestimation will happened when value estimation at least as large as the $true$ value with respect to $\phi_{true}$

$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q_{\theta}(s,\pi_{true}(s))]\geq\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q^{\pi}(s,\pi_{true}(s))]$

Such that overestimation happened when,

$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q_\theta(s,\pi_{approx}(s))]\geq\mathop{\mathbb{E}}[Q^\pi(s,\pi_{approx}(s))], \ \alpha < \min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$

In my opinion, the value of $\alpha$ just a threshold that can let the equation make sense, right ?

Comment: It seems that $\alpha$ here is the learning rate of stochastic gradient descent if you would use SGD to optimize your neural networks. In the tabular setting, this would be the same $\alpha$ as in Sutton-Barto

Comment: @matorbi Do you mean the $\alpha$ that appear in the algorithm called random-sample one-step tabular Q-learning, the third part apply one-step tabular Q-learning ? [sutton-chap08](https://lcalem.github.io/blog/2018/12/01/sutton-chap08#random-sample-one-step-tabular-q-learning)